# search string and replace using python-docx library

Tags: python, python-docx

i would like to search a word and replace it with table.
the following code is just for strings:

```
def paragraph_replace(self, search, replace):
    searchre = re.compile(search)
    for paragraph in self.paragraphs:
        paragraph_text = paragraph.text
        if paragraph_text:
            if searchre.search(paragraph_text):
                paragraph.text = re.sub(search, replace, paragraph_text)
    return paragraph_text
```

is there a way of replace it with table?

Comment: Where you define the `self.paragraphs` ?

Comment: just above.. actually self is Document @Trimax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table, like a paragraph, is a block-level content item, and the two can only appear as peers. So you cannot insert a table "in" a paragraph. You can only have a table "between" two paragraphs (or at the beginning or end of course).

Something like this might do the trick for you until we can get this feature added to the library:

```
table = document.add_table(...)
p = paragraph_to_insert_before._p
p.addprevious(table._tbl)
```

The `._p` and `._tbl` properties are the `lxml` elements underlying the `Paragraph` and `Table` objects respectively. The `addprevious()` method is an `lxml` method that in this case moves the `<w:tbl>` element to be the preceding peer of the paragraph. You can substitute `addnext()` if you want it after the paragraph.

It's a bit of a filthy hack but perhaps enough to get you by until we add that feature to the library. Let us know if it works for you :)

Comment: it is under my control. if i add a regular table (table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3,style='LightList')), it goes to the end of the document. what i need is to insert this table in the middle of the document (as you said between two paragraphs). is it possible? @scanny

Comment: Added a filthy hack that might get this done for you :)

Comment: btw i tried to workaround this.. so what i did is to place a table in the word document with one row which is empty and in the code im searching the table and just update this table.. is it a good solution?

Comment: Sure, I think that's a great solution. If you know the columns you need and maybe column headings, you can put that in the starting document and just add the rows you need. I hadn't thought of that approach :)  A little bonus is you can format the table however you want too :)